# PhoneGap transaction not triggering its first parameter after changing jQuery Mobile page and getting back

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

On a jQuery Mobile page, I call the PhoneGap Storage function like this:

```
window.database.transaction(performQuery, error);
```

And it works. I can use it several times, and it always works.

Then, I use `jQuery.mobile.changePage()` to change to a different page, then call `history.back()` from that second page, and back to the original page `performQuery()`  does not get called anymore.

I placed `alert()` functions both before and after the call to `transaction()`, and placed one at the beginning of the definition for `performQuery()`, but the third `alert()` is never reached after getting back from the second page.

This also occurs with a transaction I put on the second page. It works the first time the second page opens, but it doesn't when I get back to the former page and then back to the second page again.

Also to be noted this question might have the same answer as [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088866/phonegap-jquery-mobile-dbshell-questions), although I cannot be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the culprit is the OS. According to a workmate, Android Honeycomb gives trouble in this regard, something to do with the page change.

Anyway, things work as expected on a different Android device.